# Are function calls with arguments valid left-Hand-Side-Expressions according to ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, function-call

Are function calls with arguments valid [left-Hand-Side-Expressions](http://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-LeftHandSideExpression) according to ECMAScript ?

```
LeftHandSideExpression[Yield, Await] :
      NewExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
      CallExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
      OptionalExpression[?Yield, ?Await]
```

if we go further deep into [CallExpression](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-CallExpression) we can see below the `non-terminal CallExpression` something like this:

```
CallExpression[?Yield, ?Await] Arguments[?Yield, ?Await]
```

does that mean writing something like:

```js
alert('Hello') = 1;
```

is valid. And if you run the above code you will see that the function call takes place before the `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` is given

Comment: FWIW, this may be useful: https://timothygu.me/es-howto/ (but it doesn't answer this question).

Comment: Then do you know what:
`CallExpression[?Yield, ?Await] Arguments[?Yield, ?Await]` means. aight thats fine @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very good question, and *LeftHandSideExpression* may not be the ideal name for that production; it's used even when there may be no right-hand side. :-)

Later in the spec, when deciding whether the target of an assignment is valid, the spec checks the *AssignmentTargetType* of the expression ([here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-assignment-operators-static-semantics-early-errors)). If that type is not `simple`, the assignment is invalid. The *AssignmentTargetType* for *CallExpression Arguments* (e.g., `alert('Hello')`) and a few others (`super()`, etc.) is `invalid` ([here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-static-semantics-static-semantics-assignmenttargettype)). So you can't assign to `alert('Hello')`.

Comment: Thank You very much. but can you explain me what is the relationship of this: 
`12.15.3 Static Semantics: AssignmentTargetType
AssignmentExpression :
YieldExpression
ArrowFunction
AsyncArrowFunction
LeftHandSideExpression = AssignmentExpression
LeftHandSideExpression AssignmentOperator AssignmentExpression`
and my question. i see the that this returns `invalid` if those `non-terminals` occur in `left HandSide` of an `assignment expression` `(NOTE: this is how i understand this maybe its completely different and im wrong)` but `CallExpression` is not there.

Comment: @Kevin - Your `alert('Hello') = 1` is an assignment expression. As part of determine whether that's a valid assignment expression, there's a check that the left-hand side of that (`alert('Hello')`) has an *AssignmentTargetType* of `simple`. It doesn't, because `alert('Hello')` is *CallExpression Arguments* which has an *AssignmentTargetType* of `invalid`. So the assignment expression is invalid.

Comment: what `assignmentTargetType` of `simple` means ?

Comment: @Kevin - I think it's a way of categorizing the LeftHandSideExpressions.